# Introduction to Banach Spaces and Algebras, by Allan, Exercise 4.6

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

I am reading Introduction to Banach Spaces and Algebras, by Allan,
Unfortunately I do not succeed in completing, Exercise 4.6

> Let $(A, \|\cdot\|)$ be a normed algebra. A Banach algebra $(B, \||\cdot|\|)$ is a Banach extension of $(A, \|\cdot\|)$, if there is an isometric embedding of $(A, \|\cdot\|)$ to $(B, \||\cdot|\|)$
>
> Let $A$ and $B$ be Banachalgebra , let $I$ be a closed ideal in $B$  and $\phi: A \to B$ be a continuous homomorphism. set  $U=A\oplus I$, whit the norm $$\|(a, x)\|=\|a\|+\|x\|$$ $a\in A , x\in I$

and define a product on $U$ by setting

$$(a_1, a_2)(b_1, b_2)=(a_1 a_2,b_1 b_2+\phi(a_1)b_2+b_1\phi(a_2) )$$
$a_1, a_2\in A , b_1, b_2\in I$

prove that $(U, \|\cdot\|)$ is a Banach extension of $A$

Any comment or response is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? There are several things you need to check (i) that $U$ is an algebra (ii) that the norm on $U$ makes it complete (iii) that there is an isometric embedding of $A$ into $U$. Where did you get stuck in these verifications?

Comment: @ Rhys Steele ,I did(i) and (ii) I'm stuck (iii)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments, you indicate that your difficulty is finding an isometric embedding $A \to U$.

To do this, note that since $I$ is an ideal of $B$, it is at least an additive subgroup and hence contains $0$. We can then define $i: A \to U$ by setting $i(a) = (a,0)$. It is clear that this map is an isometric embedding by definition of $(U, \|\cdot\|_U)$.

Comment: @ Rhys Steele, ok, thank you, your answer is helpful

Comment: to prove norm on $U$ makes it complete I take the sequence $(a_n, x_n)$ in $U$ since  $A$ and $I$ are Banach space we get that norm on $U$ makes it complete